Book about a group of gamer friends that get sucked into a video game in real life
I'm trying to identify this book about a group of people (I’m pretty sure they’re like young adults) who go to a cabin, and overnight a video game sort of spawns around them. I think they had played video games together, and they’re finally meeting in real life, and that’s why they’re there.
Anyway, they’re still in the cabin and the real world, but now there’s video game stuff around them, and they have to get through the woods, which I think was a big portion while they try to find the nearest town, and then they have to find a kind of safety zone or something.
I’m pretty sure the main protagonist is a guy. I think I read it like 5 or so years ago.

That is an entire genre. Do you remember anything else? Like what abilities they got? For example, one book I remember with this plot had one character gain super hypnosis abilities, while another person became a cat girl.

Upon further review, that book is a better match than I thought. As per the [tour], you can accept an answer by clicking on the check mark by the voting buttons.

For what it is worth, the genre is generally called System Apocalypse.

Might it be Mind Games by Mark Whipple?


Eight Internet friends have an "IRL" meeting in a mountain cabin. But instead of the long weekend get-together they planned, they're suddenly caught up in the end of the world as they knew it!
They just met for the first time in real life last night, and today's group wake-up call is strange messages floating in the air telling them that something called a "System Start" has just happened. Now magic works, and technology doesn't. Cell phones won't work, cars won't start, and it's ten miles to the nearest town. Some of them have families to worry about. Some of them don't even believe this is real. And all of them have secrets they'll have to overcome if they're going to work together and make it back to town alive.
On the way, they'll meet other survivors, also confused, scared, and questioning what's happening. Ten miles doesn't seem that far, but by the end of it, they'll have faced some of the worst that the System can throw at them.
And then things really get interesting.
The small Tennessee town they're trying to reach is isolated, cut off, and surrounded by a new and terrifying world. Outside the town, ordinary creatures are becoming things out of nightmare. And inside the town, legends are coming to life...

